# BlueALSA loopback - PCM write

Tags: alsa, bluez, pcm, a2dp

As for now We are A2DP sink speaker,We open snd_pcm_open() with HW device and write PCM continuously based on asound.conf. We run bluealsa as audio streaming daemon and bluealsa-aplay as audio player.

But now onward, We need to be bluetooth A2DP source and we should use "**bluealsa**" as plugin and other audio streaming services can write with "**bluealsa**" device, So that writing audio will be sent to connected BT device using bluealsa daemon.

Here, I don't want to stop other music services for changing the pcm device from **hw0,1** to **bluealsa** once after BT got connected. I want to continue as it is and bluealsa plugin needs to add/loopback simultaneously in the pcm device.

**Host stack :** Bluez 5.72

**Audio stack :** BlueALSA 4.1.1

Correct me if I'm wrong. I am new to alsa and PCM stuff

Comment: I found something here. For this requirement we can create Virtual PCM with subdevices using "sudo modprobe snd-aloop" and it will give you New card (card 1),devices (0,1) and 8 subdevices (0 to 7) for individual devices. Then, All music services need to open and write into Virtual pcm , say example (hw:1,0,4) instead of direct (hw:0,1) and we will get loopback on (hw:1,1,4), Here we can use "alsaloop" to capture from hw:1,1,4 and playback to required pcm . We can kill it and restart it dynamically based on the output selection. No need to disturb the audio writing music sources.